# How does linux manage threads stack

Tags: multithreading, elf

On intel x86 32/64 bits architecture, each thread owns it own stack.
Where the kernel switch between threads of the same process, stack and registers of current threads are backuped somewhere. I suppose it is in a stack ?

Does that mean if i have N thread on my process, i will have N+1 stacks in the process memory ? Or is it managed by kernel ? Can i thread read the stack of another thread if it knows esp/bsp of that thread ?
(i am talking about threads of the same process)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where the kernel switch between threads of the same process, stack and registers of current threads are backuped somewhere. I suppose it is in a stack ?

Yes, thats correct. Usually, a rescheduling is triggered by a `timer interrupt`. A `timer interrupt`, like any other hardware-interrupt[1], requests the CPU to stop working on what it is working at the moment and execute some special code, the `interrupt service routine`. The kernel can set this up itself, so it is just a function provided by the kernel. Usually, the first thing a kernel does when an interrupt happens is, it pushes all registers onto the stack. The only thing the kernel has to save is the top of the stack, the `esp`. When the kernel now switches to another thread, all it has to do is load the new threads `esp` and pop back all the registers.

> Does that mean if i have N thread on my process, i will have N+1 stacks in the process memory ?

You'll most likely have N stacks in your memory and N stacks in kernel memory, as a interrupt, calling into kernel code, loads another stack. Usually, every thread has it's own kernel stack, but don't quote me on that.

> Can i thread read the stack of another thread if it knows esp/bsp of that thread ? (i am talking about threads of the same process)

Yes, you can. Threads in the same process share the same virtual address space, so if you know where exactly a threads stack is you can access this memory.

---

[1]: A hardware interrupt is triggered by the [Programmable Interrupt Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_Interrupt_Controller) from the "outside" of the CPU when something happens, like a key-press on your keyboard. There are also software interrupts, which are triggered by the cpu/the software itself, either intended or to handle an error (division by zero). Software interrupts are one way to implement systemcalls, because you can not call ring-0 code from ring-3 code. A interrupt however can jump "up" to ring-0 if the [TSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_state_segment) is set up to do so.